# rails5: generic grid - how to get column names for current search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wan to do a generic grid, that could be used in my app to show data from different Models. As I am a newbie in RoR - please let me know if my "vision" is ok, or i should change the way i think about this problem:

Controller:

```
    class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      authorize_resource

        def index
            @current_scope = params[:role]
            @users = User.select(:id, :email, :role, :last_sign_in_at).role(@current_scope)
        end

end
```

User Model:

```
scope :role, -> (role) {where('role = ?', role) if role.present?}
```

Index view:

```
<%= render '/layouts/shared/grid', object: @users%>
```

Grid partial:

```
<% object.column_names.each do |column_name| %>
                <th><%= column_name %></th>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that i can show always ALL columns (that is what ActiveRecord::Relation returns), not only columns for parameters selected in my query.  I see few potential solutions - which one would be the best?

1. usage of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query - if i do so, i could use then .columns method that returns what i need. But i am not sure if i like it...
2. usage of search_params instead of query result to iterate

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `values` method. It's not very documented but it returns parsed sql query.

For this query:

```
User.select(:id, :email, :role,:last_sign_in_at).role(@current_scope).values
```

It returns something like this:

```
{:select=>[:id, :email, :role, :last_sign_in_at], :where=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation::WhereClause:0x007fe0d3b29bf0 @predicates=["role = admin"], @binds=[]>}
```

If a query will not use `select` when `values` will not return `select` result too. In this case, you need to use `column_names`.

Too I can recommend you wrap table code to decorator. This is raw example:

```
class TableDecorator

  def initialize(scope)
    @scope = scope
  end

  def header_columns
    scope.values[:select] || @scope.column_names
  end

  def columns
    @scope
  end
end

# controller
@table = TableDecorator.new(@users)

# index view
<%= render '/layouts/shared/grid', locals: {table: @table} %>

# grid partial
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% table.header_columns.each do |column_name| %>
         <th><%= column_name %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

      <% table.columns.each do |item| %>
        <tr>
          <% table.header_columns.each do |column_name| %>
             <td><%= item[column_name] %></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx! i like your solution - much more "clean" that my :) Unfortunatelly i don't have time today to do it in my app - but promise that i will make a short update here as soon as i do it :)

Comment: you propose to use here a decorator pattern. i agree - it makes sense (we split the code that generated dynamically grid control from the code that fils our grid with data). I've never used decorator pattern in rails before - do you think that it makes sense to use draper gem and include it "by default" if we want to use decorators?